# get LiveData Transformations in loop android

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, android-livedata, observers

I am getting all categories from a different endpoint, different repository. That is giving me all categories. Now i want to run this categories in loop and write observer to get all the items of each category.
In other words -
I want to get FeedItems of all categories one by one because i have to fire separate endpoint to each category. I have list of all categories.

I am able to get single category's items by writing below code, but do not know how to get multiple.

In viewModal i am doing below code for to single category Observer

```
  val categoryByIdItems: LiveData<Resource<List<FeedItem>>> = Transformations
        .switchMap(categoryByIdParam) { input ->
            input.ifExists { catId, shouldFetch ->
                feedRepository.loadCategoryByIdFeed(catId.toString(), shouldFetch)
            }
        }
```

if i use above code it will give me feedItems of one category by calling load function

```
fun load(categories:List<Category>,shouldFetch:Boolean = false){
    setCategoryByIdRequest(categories[0].id, shouldFetch)
}
```

I want to run setCategoryByIdRequest in loop based on categories, i can do that.
I am using this code to get first category items in fragment file

```
viewModel.categoryByIdItems.observe(this, Observer { resource ->
})
```

if i run the loop for `viewModel.categoryByIdItems.observe` than layout adds in fragment but because of same observer all are same.

But i am not sure how can i get categoryByIdItems in loop as observe in fragment.
as categoryByIdItems i am defining in view-modal first and using that in fragment but i want that dynamic based on number of categories.

Sorry for my writing as i do not know how to explain more to tell you what i want. I am new with LiveData and Transformations.
I am not using DB, using apis to get data. let me know if you want to find more code about repository, view modal or fragment, i'll provide you.

Comment: Any response, please

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to get all category in a list first from DB and then using kotlin filter to fetch by ID like this

DAO

@Query("SELECT * FROM categories_table")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List>

VIEWMODEL

```
private val _categories = DAO.getAll()

val categories : LiveData<Category>
   get() = _categories
```

ACTIVITY/ FRAGMENT

```
viewModel.categories .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->

if(it!=null){

//filter your data
})
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong.. i already have all categories data in a List using different endpoint, i want to get category's post with different endpoint and repository. So i want to run a loop as i told in my question.